# For a structured causal model, if two RVs are conditionally independent on X, are they also independent when only one of them is conditioned on X?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, causal-diagrams, causality

Does
$(A \perp B)|X$ implies $(A|X)\perp B$ ? 
I managed to derive it, but it feels wrong.

Here is my derivation. Is it flawed?

> If $(A \perp B)|X$ then $(A|X) \perp (B|X)$ and therefore $p[A|(X, (B|X) ) ]=p[A|X]$
>
> in addition: $p[A|(X, (B|X) ) ] = p[A|(X, B) ]$, because both $X$ and $B$ are given.
>
> We can conclude that $p[A|(X, B) ] = p[A|X]$ and therefore $(A|X)\perp B$

EDIT:

Here is a relevant use case: 
1) Let's say we have a causal graph B->X->A, with the structured eq. model (SEM)

$B = Nb$, s.t. $Nb$ ~ $p(Nb)$

$X = f1(B, Nx)$, s.t. $Nx$ ~ $p(Nx)$

$A = f2(X, Na)$, s.t. $Na$ ~ $p(Na)$

Na, Nb, Nx may (or may not) be independent, yet we definitely know that the conditional independence $(A \perp B)|X$ holds, does it implies that $(A|X)\perp B$ ?

Note: Under the SCM, (A|X) is a random variable that depends on Na.

2) What happens if the graph (and SEM) is reversed A->X->B. Would it also imply $(A|X)\perp B$ ?

Comment: $A|X$ is not a random variable. What do you mean by independence with $B$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $A|X$ Can be a random variable. For example:  $A = X + noise$, s.t. noise~N(0,1)

Comment: No.  Conditioning applies to the whole of the conjunction being measured; you cannot condition one conjunct and not the other.

Comment: @GrahamKemp, can you tell what is flawed in my derivation? Or give a counter example?

Comment: The whole concept is off.  Conditioning is not a set operation performed on events being measured.  Conditioning is an aspect of the probability measure function itself.

Comment: Please state what you think would be the precise definition of $A \mid X$ being independent of $B$.

Comment: @NateEldredge if their joint probability equals the product of their probabilities. I.e $p[ (A|X) , B ] = p[A|X] p[B]$

Comment: I don't know what $p[(A \mid X), B]$ means.  Of what subset of the sample space are you taking the probability?

Comment: @NateEldredge, I am not sure that I understand your question, but I edited the question and added a more specific case based on causal diagrams.